# ReactJS, Django , GraphQL - Uploading file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to upload a file in frontend and send the data to Django backend using graphql.

```
function Integrations() {
  const [importTranscations] = useMutation(IMPORT_TRANSACTIONS);

  function onChange({
    target: {
      validity,
      files: [file],
    },
  }) {
    if (validity.valid) {
      importTranscations({ variables: { file } });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        padding: "20px",
      }}
    >
      <input type="file" required onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Integrations;
```

When I inspect the network tab and observe the graphql api call, I can observe that an empty object is being sent as `'file'`:

[image: image of the network tab with the api call]

I have also added logs in the Django backend where I am using [graphene-file-upload](https://pypi.org/project/graphene-file-upload/) module. I am getting `file` as an empty Dictionary.

URLs:

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from graphene_file_upload.django import FileUploadGraphQLView

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("graphql/", csrf_exempt(FileUploadGraphQLView.as_view())),
]
```

Mutations:

```py
import graphene
from graphene_file_upload.scalars import Upload


class ImportTransactionsMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        file = Upload(required=True)

    task_id = graphene.String()

    def mutate(self, info, file):
        print("@@ DEBUGGING @@ -> file", file)
        task_id = "sample"
        return ImportTransactionsMutation(task_id=task_id)
```

This is the output that I am seeing in the console:

```
@@ DEBUGGING @@ -> file {}
```

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/clever-browser-74wz4x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to codesandbox. You can open the network tab and check the graphql API.

Comment: I believe that you need to use a graphql-upload package to support File uploads. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/data/file-uploads/ Also, check if your API is actually receiving the file. (console.log and await the data)

Comment: @SlothOverlord I am using Django backend and I have integrated it with the [graphene-file-upload](https://pypi.org/project/graphene-file-upload/) module. `graphql-upload` is for the frontend?

Comment: You don't need to use graphql-upload if you use graphene-file-upload. But still you need to check if the file has actually arrived at your backend. I think that graphql represents files as {} a variable. Simply await for the data and console.log the arriving file

Comment: @SlothOverlord Based on the backend logs, I can confirm that I am getting empty object in the backend as well. Updated the question!